# ChangeDectection OnPush: ngFor is not triggered while direct call is

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngfor, angular2-changedetection

I have a problem with ngFor while using Angular OnPush ChangeDetection.

This is my code:

**app.state.ts**

```
export class Node {
    title: string;
}

export class Tree {
    nodes: Array<Node>
}
```

**home.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    tree$: Observable<Tree>;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.tree$ = this.store.select(state => state.tree);
    }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
Number of nodes: {{ (tree$ | async).nodes.length }}
<div *ngFor="let node of (tree$ | async).nodes" class="node-list">
    {{ node.title }}
</div>
```

By default, the **nodes** array is empty. When I dispatch an action to add a new node into the **nodes** array. The **number of nodes** in the template changes, but the node list is still empty.

I don't understand why. Do you have any idea? Thanks!

**UPDATE**
By adding *ngIf in a container that contains node list, it is working.

```
<div *ngIf="tree$">
    <div *ngFor="let node of (tree$ | async).nodes" class="node-list">
        {{ node.title }}
    </div>
</div>
```

But I still do not understand why. Could you explain this behavior, please?

Comment: When you add a new node into the nodes, do you use the `push` method on the `nodes` array or you create a new array? I mean do you mutate the array or creates a new Array on adding new node? Also can you please post your reducer code which adds a new node in the `nodes` array?

Comment: Yes, I created a completely new array @user2216584. What makes me confused is why the number of nodes changes if there is a problem in my code

Comment: Add the code for your reducer where you update the state and where you dispatch the action.

Answer (score 1):

(tree$ | async).nodes is going to cause an exception if the tree is not initialised.

Try

```
<ng-container *ngIf="tree$ | async as tree">
  Number of nodes: {{ tree.nodes.length }}
  <div *ngFor="let node of tree.nodes" class="node-list">
    {{ node.title }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

This will not crash for when the tree is undefined before the first action is dispatched.

Answer (score -1):

`ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` is designed to improve performance of a component by ignore checking changes internally to component and its directives. This will only just check change for some transferring decorators like `@Input`. So in this case even if we declare `tree$` as `async`, the component can not detect that is an update to update into `DOM`. The number of nodes in the template changes because `length` is an immutable built-in property for any `Array` in Javascript which is assigned to a different memory location everytime its value changes. In contrast, `(tree$ | async).nodes` is referred to the same memory location even if its property is changed.

There are several options you can check to fix it:

- Create a **shalow copy** of when update value in your `Store` - [Angular2 ngFor OnPush Change Detection with Array Mutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829951/angular2-ngfor-onpush-change-detection-with-array-mutations?rq=1)
- And mark for change so that Angular lifecycle to detect it https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: tree$ | async is watching an observable and is perfect for ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. When observables emit change detection is triggered.