# Re-render the particular component based on detected changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 2 simple components. One is `parent` the other is `child`. The `parent` component has an `Array`, For each element in the `Array`, It renders the `child` component.

**parent.component.ts**

```js
export class parent implements OnInit {

  data: CustomType[] = [
     {
       id: "child1",
       records: [] // array of string
     },
     {
       id: "child2",
       records: [] // array of string
     }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```html
<section>
  <ChildComponent *ngFor="let child of data | async" [obj]="child"/>
</section>
```

**child.component.ts**

```js
export class child implements OnInit {

  // The data is passed from the parent component
  @Input() obj: CustomType;

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**child.component.html**

```html
<div>
  {{ obj.id }}
</div>
```

**The Problem**

The current code works just fine. But the issue is if the `records` of an element change in the `array`, It re-renders all the children components. I want to re-render the exact component only.

I am wondering how to use the **onPush Change Detection** here.

**For Example:**

If `data[0].records` changes, It should re-render the `data[0]`'s child component only.

Comment: This stack'answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829951/angular2-ngfor-onpush-change-detection-with-array-mutations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the trackBy function so that it does not render everthing but only renders the one where the trackBy function is changed!

html file

```
<section>
  <ChildComponent *ngFor="let child of data | async; trackBy: trackBy" [obj]="child"/>
</section>
```

ts file

```
  trackBy(index, item) {
    return item.id;
  }
```

reference [here](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5#:%7E:text=The%20trackBy%20function%20takes%20the,That%27s%20all.)

Comment: I think I need to add `item.records ` instead of `item.id` coz `id` never change.

Comment: @BadPiggie You need to add a dummy property called `toggle` set it to true initially, whenever you update records properties, toggle this property, since its under trackby function it will conditionally render it and your issue will be solved without watching records