# RxJS observable of objects property

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to observe changes of a property with RxJS.

```
interface Test {
  required: boolean;
  toObserve: boolean;
}

class TestClass {
  @Input() subject: Subject<Test>;

  registerHandlers() {
    this.subject.filter(element => element.required).subscribe(next =>
      // Observe a property of every element that was registered
      Observable.of(next.toObserve).subscribe(val => {
        if (val) {
          // DO SOMETHING
        } else {
          // DO SOMETHING ELSE
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

I got a subject into which newly created objects are pushed. Several components subscribe on these and should react on different property changes.

In the above example if `toObserve` is set I want the component to do something. This works exactly once currently - Depending on the value the element has when it is registered with `subject.next(element)` the correct path is executed.

However as soon as I change the value of `element.toObserve` nothing is happening and the subscription seems to have no effect anymore.

Comment: You're only pushing one object to the subject, and then you're changing that same object?

Comment: I push several objects to the subscription but I want to listen to the changes of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a subscribe into a subscribe is not recommended. I would rather create an operators chain to your subject and subscribe to it:

If you want to perform some side effects in your components depending on a specific property in your stream, you can use the do operator:

```
interface Test {
  required: boolean;
  toObserve: boolean;
}

class TestClass implements OnInit {
  @Input() subject: Subject<Test>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerHandlers().subscribe();
  }

  registerHandlers() {
    return this.subject
     .filter(element => element.required)
     .do(next => {
        if (next.toObserve) {
          // DO SOMETHING
        } else {
          // DO SOMETHING ELSE
        }
     });    
  }
}
```

Comment: Would I need to subscribe to this too then? I think I still miss something to fully understand how this subscriptions work. Would this snippet in `do` react on the change of property every time without pushing the object to the subject again?

Comment: Here, your subject is the emitter.
It means that every time you change your value, you will have to call `this.subject.next(myNewValue)` to execute the code in registerHandlers(). You also have to subscribe to the function otherwise there's no point executing this code if there's no receiver. 
But you'll always have to push the data manually to the subject, it won't do it automatically.

Comment: Mh ok I understand so each time some component changes anything I have to push the hole object again to all other components in order to react on it. I will need to rethink my logic then... One more question before I go though my hole code again: There will not be a new object reference or a clone operation? So when I push it again and ask for equality (To remove it from a data table for example) the objects will be the same as the very first instance I pushed (just other prop values)?

Comment: Even if you change properties on the object you push in your subject, you are not changing the object reference, so it should be the same ( I am not sure though, it is best to do a quick test). 
I would suggest to put your subject and your function in a service, so every component that needs the data can subscribe to it. Don't forget to unsubscribe in the ngDestroy of your components to prevent data leakage.

Comment: Thanks for your insight I already wondered how it would work when I have several thousand subscriptions online... Is there an easy way to see "what happened" to the object? i.e. Which property has changed?

Comment: Regarding the subscriptions, you don't need to unsubscribe from observables that has completed and from those observables dealed by angular (like route object or async pipe), so it should lower the count ^^.
In order to know what has changed to your object, I am afraid there's no easy answer. I find this answer when searching for it :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44396986/4693209
I hope it will help you somehow.

Comment: Small update on this: I don't want `do` but subscribe directly as `do` discards the side effects on subsequent subscriptions. Made it work as I wanted more or less.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I reckon you didn't completely understand how subscription is to be done properly.

You have your subject

```
@Input() subject: Subject<Test>;
```

and you want to trigger actions whenever the subject changes. Then put this subscription into your ngOnInit()-method:

```
this.subject.subscribe(value => {
   // and here goes your evaluation
   if(value.toObserve) {
      // do something
   } else {
      // do something else
   }
});
```

and you can go even further and do something like this

```
this.subject.subscribe(value => {
   // and here goes your evaluation
   if(value.toObserve) {
      // do something
   } else {
      // do something else
   }

   if(value.required) {
      // do something
   } else {
      // do something else
   }
});
```

Comment: Putting the subscription in the constructor can be dangerous. It looks like that the property subject could be undefined at the moment the constructor is executed

Comment: Doesn't that mean that in a nested Object, this approach has to check the if(value.toObserver) every time anything in the whole object changes? If this is the case, this approach is easy but can get inperformant really fast. For example if the the if-clause contains a bit more complex function or the object is a little bigger with components changing the object on hovers for example.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Of course one has to make sure that the performance is not slowed down too much. But this is how subscriptions basically have to be done. How you optimize the update-process of those subjects is up to you. --- If you'd run a little test by putting all the lifecycle hooks Angular provides (OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit and so on) inside a single component containing only one input field and let them all fire an output using console.log() whenever they get called, you'd be surprised or maybe shocked how often Angular is passing / triggering all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I do this, in this example I used a attribute type number, but, you can use another like "Test"

```
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CoinsService {

  private total: Subject<number> = new ReplaySubject<number>(1); //This is my attribute
  private total$ = this.total.asObservable(); //This is my observable

  constructor() {
    this.total.next(0); //Init my parameter
   }

  async add(coins: number) {
    // I must subscribe for take the value of attribute
    this.total$
      .pipe(
         take(1) // Guaranty that is the one time and release the subscription
      )
    .subscribe(async accumate => {
      this.total.next(accumate + coins);// Set the new value
    });
  }

  getTotal(): Observable<number> {
    return this.total$;//Return this observable for client subscription on every change
  }

}
```

That is.

I hope help you.