# Subscribing to Map Data Structure in JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, observable

I have been trying to observe changes on a Map Object in JavaScript but for some reason only can observe the creation of the object. Do observables not work when adding/removing data from a Map?

Here is the observable:

```
  test(): Observable<Map<string, Object>> {
    return of(this.testModel.test());
}
```

This is me subscribing to it:

```
test(): Observable<Map<string, Object>> {

let mapOb = this.testModel.test();
    return Observable.create((obsrvr) => {
      const originalSet = mapOb.set;
      const originalDelete = mapOb.delete;
      mapOb.set = (...args) => {
        obsrvr.next(originalSet.call(mapOb, ...args));
      };

      mapOb.delete = (...args) => {
        obsrvr.next(originalDelete.call(mapOb, ...args));
      }
    });
}
```

I see the log statement during the creation of the Map, but if i add any new entries to the Map nothing is logged. Anyone know why this may be happening?

I get an error at maoOb.set and mapOb.delete:

```
Type '(key: string, value: Object) => void' is not assignable to type '(key: string, value: Object) => Map<string, Object>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, Object>'
```

Comment: Are you referring to RxJS `Observable`s? If so, searching for this returned multiple results, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/32683488/438992, https://gist.github.com/jayphelps/d8641e7213b56d368e7b, etc.

Comment: *"if i add any new entries to the Map nothing is logged"* - why *would* anything be logged? You don't have an observable of changes to the map, you have an observable that emits a single value, the map itself.

Comment: Your code is incomplete causing confusion. Do test return an observable of itself? What does this.testModel.test() returns? An promise?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah I am referring the the RxJS Observable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you clarify more? I had a suspicion I may be observing thew wrong thing. How do you observe changes to the map?

Comment: You can't, maps don't expose that. You could write some kind of proxy object that did, though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Hi, I really wanted some feedback on the answer I provided. Can you please have a look over it and check if it would have any side effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You current approach doesn't seem correct when you want to listen to addition/deletion of data in a Map.

You are simply returning an Observable using `of(Object Reference)`, this will no way know about things that you are doing with the Object you are passing with it.

You need to have an Observable which emits when you perform set() or delete() over the MapInstance.

You may modify your Map instance this way to achieve what you desire.

```
createObservable(mapOb) {
  return Observable.create((obsrvr) => {
    const originalSet = mapOb.set;
    const originalDelete = mapOb.delete;
    mapOb.set = (...args) => {
      const setReturn = originalSet.call(mapOb, ...args);
      obsrvr.next(setReturn);
      return setReturn;
    };

    mapOb.delete = (...args) => {
      const deleteReturn = originalDelete.call(mapOb, ...args);
      obsrvr.next(deleteReturn);
      return deleteReturn;
    }
  });

}
```

Pass the map to createObservable() method and subscribe to it. In this method, I have modified the `set` and `delete` methods of your map, so that it emits a value when those methods are called.

I have created a dummy example for the answer: [Link.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kndjqj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I get an error:

```
Type '(key: string, value: Object) => void' is not assignable to type '(key: string, value: Object) => Map<string, Object>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, Object>'.
```

Comment: @BlueMoose, can you update your question with whatever you have tried and the line where you get the error?

Comment: Actually it did work. My bad. Thank you soo much for you help!!

Comment: @BlueMoose: We were not returning values `set/delete`, that is why it was complaining.See the edit, it shouldn't complain about it now.