# TypeScript: Factor out function applied on all of Object's properties

Tags: typescript

So assume we have some generic function

```
function change<T>(something: T): IWhatever<T> {}
```

So I may have an object that looks like this

```
const stuff = {
    key1: change(1),
    key2: change('hello'),
    key3: change(false)
}
```

Is there anyway I can make a simpler object that looks like this

```
const stuff = {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 'hello',
    key3: false
}
```

And pass the simpler object into some function that spits out the first object, with appropriate TypeScript typing? Also assume that the simpler object could change properties whenever, and "some function" would still produce the proper complex one.

I can't figure it out, and don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Perhaps this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683488/rxjs-observing-object-updates-and-changes

Comment: Not concrete enough. Is your change function reversible? (Can you go back from IWhatever<T> returned by change to the argument of change?)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can achieve this by using `Mapped Types`. All you need to use 2 type mappings :

1. To strip `IWhatever<T>`
2. Apply the stripping operation to every property

```js
//  a weird interface
interface IWhatever<T> {
  whut: T;
}

// a weird function that wraps everything into that weird interface
function change<T>(something: T): IWhatever<T> { return { whut: something }; }


// general type that defines all properties has to be type of IWhatever<T>
type Whatevered<R> = {
  [key in keyof R]: IWhatever<R[key]>
}

// this object suits the type of we defined above
const stuff = {
  key1: change(1),
  key2: change('hello'),
  key3: change(false)
}

// this map strips the IWhatever type
type UnWhateverify<T> = T extends IWhatever<infer R> ? R : T;

// this applies strping to all properties of the object
type Cleanser<T> = { [Key in keyof T]: UnWhateverify<T[Key]> }

// this function is a dummy(magic) function that illustrates the type action
function MagicJhonson<R, T extends Whatevered<R>>(item: T): Cleanser<T> {
  let cleansed = {} as any;
  // doing the cleaning here
  for (let key in item)
    cleansed[key] = item[key].whut; // that general type definition `Whatevered<R>` makes this valid  
  // you can also skip that and do some cast to any action here.

  return cleansed as Cleanser<T>;
}

const cleansedStuff = MagicJhonson(stuff);

console.log(cleansedStuff.key1) // number
console.log(cleansedStuff.key2) // string
console.log(cleansedStuff.key3) // boolean


// another dummy function to reverse apply the operation
function JhonsonMagic<T>(item: T): Whatevered<T> {
  let whuts = {} as any;
  for (let key in item) {
    whuts[key] = change(item[key])
  }

  return whuts as Whatevered<T>;
}

const oldStuff = JhonsonMagic(cleansedStuff);

console.log(oldStuff.key1) // whut :number
console.log(oldStuff.key2) // whut :string
console.log(oldStuff.key3) // whut :boolean
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=60&pc=44#code/PTAEoQ1B3BTBLATgE1PAdgF1ogZhAY1gCgNs9DZQBJAdQAsJsA3HAHgBUA+UAb2PDR6AV0wAuUBwDcxAL7FiISDAQpQuYegKZ4Ae3ShMjTDEQQADgGdQsVogCeRjAHM0WXYeMqkqMjnxExBpaOvqgBIzozrCcXAAUlroAtrBOURIcAJQSdMa27Nx8oIipwogGvDAi4qCJKWmuslKg8gpK0eg4EAA2hvbmVEZMoMiwuBiw1j295oi6A4g6k6CM1pgeAEaD-VS6uDQMTPmIscSYO6CHLDiwyGwASjwAvHwCoADaANaw9m6g3-Y9qB7gBdHJXY4PL4-EFcORtMBOay6DYAK1g2lqwngmDW9G2A1AQLgIzGE1QEA2ulYxAI+ksJgZwlw+xe-HAAIAjBIIhAorA4pzMgAaN4AgBMPMi0TiAHJ8d1urpZSKxT8AMxSvky-DdSywTLwxSI+jwaxJCy1TCIeBWTxUXJHOx9AZnC4AVXQELs8Fw9lioBeHBsAA9sOhkNZHdcThhcDhgTwAPzA0AZGTGzxmyDmczdeDLBmIcwuQweaagWbzHBLZH7Iy7NEYzBuwkAYW6sD5+pOhTZHwA0j8-gCgRwwaBPd6cL7-Rx3kP7LCWgis9Zgto9AZs1BkMIkkl7HELc54ARMupNJuwkMTPBFcIi0c8QSqIRQuggleP6AALIQU8CAAKXoel9AeYVJFDcNI0uPI7FuB4uHiHFYCSDJslADsu3QHsA3ZUBOxMAhO27W5Az4WRICmdB7BkcAlGQXRSwbcJSPQUt8RKN5cF0RBQDiIj-mHDA0GwJJDXAcASJw-VkGhJcKNQpIFJBAA6IRRGaJRb1ADoul6c5CVGcYOJ-AADacSjuR5zNAC1vjxbNmB6eBUFAN4lEBYRwj5SA9Q8SxPltTxhj5VAmNqZIqAICAGTLSBaMga8DC42A1IUcASkwMoDBksiKWsbCyN7LgZFaOlcOI9i5IAZRylkKP-QCQLA9AEga3BMgzSrEk7NSlWcOJ8tw256uZXA1K5C8lHQfctkQWkwP6wbhpqsbOqmn5xRmsAixcJbcN0FbdCGka6s2gF1V20AqWOnCFEzPldAbfi9wPX4Nx-dZimOfUczzX5WOrMwPy-EIt1AVqjvQZqz1iOJlIwiQrMQwoCKEzTcQo3gqLixK6J4viBKEgE-mUi8CMEapLFUijeX5RHxNUySVzebLcqqUQpmsVG7m4cqFF6kxjuQcbGpeaHElhgCzzW2SNom7qheW9LVtF8XJum0AlCxtM5qSBbDr6tXTriDXLu2m69bEfaomN+6BrNi2Jq2+xrp1sAbbu9igA)

Comment: With this, am I also able to go in the reverse direction? Start with the cleansed, and end with the IWhatever'd object?

Comment: @ZeroSevenTen you need just a function that returns `Whatevered<T>`. See the updated answer.